# Android : Upload image to PHP server

Tags: php, android, http-post, image-uploading

I have write a script to upload an image taken from camera to my server. I get **200OK** response but I don't see my image on my server in uploads/ folder :

[image]

Maybe my script contain an error. Could you help me please ?

My example is the following link : http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Here is the compleete Android class :

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class New_annonce_act_step3 extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 100;   

    TextView tvPath;
    TextView txtHaut;
    ImageView preview;
    File destination;
    String imagePath;
    ImageButton takePhoto;
    Button btnCreate;

    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.nouvelle_annonce_step3);

        // Change color of action bar
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0099CC")));

        preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nouvelle_annonce_step3_phototaken_preview);
        btnCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nouvelle_annonce_step3_btn) ;
        txtHaut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nouvelle_annonce_step3_texteHaut);
        takePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nouvelle_annonce_choose_image);
        preview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        upLoadServerUri = "http://mywebsite.com/database/PDO/uploadFile.php";

        String name = dateToString(new Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss");
        destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), name + ".jpg");

        takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(destination));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(New_annonce_act_step3.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {              
                        uploadFile(imagePath);
                    }
                }).start();        
            }

        });





    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ){
            try {
                preview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                takePhoto.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txtHaut.setText("Cette image est parfaite !");
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(destination);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 10;
                imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
                Log.d("INFO", "PATH === " +imagePath);
                //tvPath.setText(imagePath);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
                preview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else{
            tvPath.setText("Request cancelled");
        }
    }

    public String dateToString(Date date, String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return df.format(date);
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;  
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
            dialog.dismiss(); 
            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" +imagePath);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            try { 

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename="+ fileName + "" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(New_annonce_act_step3.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
                }    

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();  
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(New_annonce_act_step3.this, "MalformedURLException", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();  
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(New_annonce_act_step3.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);  
            }
            dialog.dismiss();       
            return serverResponseCode; 

        } // End else block 
    } 

}
```

And here is the **PHP script :**

```
<?php
    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to catch the error from the php script.

Comment: Do you think that an error occurs in PHP? Even if i get 200 OK response?

Comment: Hi @wawanopoulos I'm using same code and I am stuck at 200 OK response as of now. I gave the folder permission and the script added by Alan C also works and writes data. However, my image is not being written. It shows file uploaded and gives http 200 ok and i goto server and run the php file and I get output as 'fail'. Can you provice any help on this? Thanks

Comment: Also, do you have any reference for downloading the image from web server to android? thanks

Comment: I got it working. It was an error in writing bytes :) Thanks for the post though. It really helped me.

Comment: You have a variable named imagePath declared in your class, one named sourceFileUri in your declaration of uploadFile(), and another named fileName in your implementation of uploadFile(). It seems like all these have the same value, and you use them interchangeable in your code. You should just use one variable for that, probably the one declared at the top of your class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you verified that the user `apache` (or whichever user php is running as) has permissions to write to the directory specified in `$file_path`?

Put the following code in the same directory as your PHP script is, and then visit it in your web browser.

```
<?php

$file_path = 'uploads/';

$success = file_put_contents($file_path . "afile", "This is a test");

if($success === false) {
    echo "Couldn't write file";
} else {
    echo "Wrote $success bytes";
}

?>
```

Does this give a success message or an error message?

If it gives an error message, trying changing the ownership of the `uploads` directory.

Comment: Problem solved ! I forget to set 777 rights for uploads/ directtory